# pygame sound with Python 3.5 on Windows

Tags: python, pygame

im currently having trouble with the python 3rd party library pygame.
Other posts on stackoverflow didn't help me so i opened a new post.
I want to load a *.mp3 file into the program and play it. My code so far (copied from other posts):

```
import pygame,time,sys

pygame.mixer.init(frequency=22050, size=-16, channels=2, buffer=4096)
print ("Mixer settings", pygame.mixer.get_init())
print ("Mixer channels", pygame.mixer.get_num_channels())
pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(1.0)
pygame.mixer.music.load("test.mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.play()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
   clock.tick(30)
```

Here is a link to a screenshot from the Windows Sound panel: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Plm32.png

I see that there is some output, but i cant hear anything on my headphones.
I hope some has an idea what the problem is.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check your hardware/audio drivers. It doesn't sound like (pardon the pun!) an issue with python or pygame. Does your audio work outside python? Also, if you've got other programs open, they can sometimes take control of your audio drivers and not allow other programs (in this case python) to output.

Comment: Drivers are up to date and everything works fine, i tried to close all other applications but the result is still the same.

Comment: Can I suggest a reinstall of pygame and perhaps python?